# Is it correct to return 200 Ok HTTP status for a POST request?

Tags: api, http, post

Usually, we use POST to create a resource on the server-side.
So ideally if everything goes right, the server should respond either with a `201 Created` HTTP status or in case of an asynchronous operation with `202 Accepted` HTTP status.

Is there any valid scenario where a POST request can be returning a `200 OK` HTTP status?
Or should we never use `200 OK` HTTP status for a POST request?

Answer (score 13):

I see 200 as a very common response to POST requests on internet. It's fine to use it.

From [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> 6.3.1.  200 OK
>
> The 200 (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.
> The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method.
> For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning
> of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> GET  a representation of the target resource;
>
> HEAD  the same representation as GET, but without the
> representation
> data;
>
> POST  a representation of the status of, or results obtained from,
> the action;
>
> PUT, DELETE  a representation of the status of the action;
>
> OPTIONS  a representation of the communications options;
>
> TRACE  a representation of the request message as received by the
> end
> server.

And section 4.3.3:

> Responses to POST requests are only cacheable when they include
> explicit freshness information (see Section 4.2.1 of [RFC7234]).
> However, POST caching is not widely implemented. For cases where an
> origin server wishes the client to be able to cache the result of a
> POST in a way that can be reused by a later GET, the origin server MAY
> send a 200 (OK) response containing the result and a Content-Location
> header field that has the same value as the POST's effective request
> URI (Section 3.1.4.2).

Comment: but can we call it a restful approach in case if we are using it to develop an API?

Comment: @DesirePRG Sure, why not?  RESTful is a description of the architectural properties of a remote API.  It doesn't even need to use HTTP to be RESTful, much less use specific return codes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You can return `200 Ok` HTTP status, but you SHOULD return a response **BODY**.

In general, we have 3 options according to your API requirements:

1. Return `201 Created` HTTP status, with **EMPTY BODY**.
   In case you don't need to return a response body.
2. Return `200 Ok` HTTP status, with **BODY**.
   In case you need to return a response body [containg created resource].
3. Return `202 Accepted` HTTP status, with **EMPTY BODY**.
   In case the action will be queued.

Comment: Sorry the 201 should return the new created resource as is explain at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201

Comment: @freedeveloper not necessarily. With `201 Created` it's sufficient to provide the resource locator via `Location` header.